# Batch File - Is there a way to insert something like a page break to have different colored text?

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe, colors

I'm writing a batch file and wanted to know if there is a way to separate colors with different lines of text to highlight something. The batch file would have to be able to run on   different PC's so without downloading something either,  just want commands in the batch file to make other lines of text a different color without changing all text that color on the screen

Color 04 (Black bkg and Text Red)

Example:

Please select a choice     <---  This line would be Red Text with Black background (color O4)

Please select 1 to xxxxx    <----  These 2 next lines the text is Blue  (color 01)

Please Select 2 to xxxxx     <------     this line text is also blue

Comment: This is very doable in batch- [In this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64399689/12343998) I demonstrate a menu macro that colors text and highlights selected / unselected options using color. Depending on the windows version, colors are displayed using either [VT100 sequences](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) {Windows 10} or a `Findstr` based color print macro. Colors may also be disabled.

Comment: @Mister_G - If you are interested in my deleted PowerShell batch helper much simpler logic and code wise solution still, I will be happy to undelete it so you can see it again. Just tag me back as `@ITThugNinja` and let me know.

Answer (score 2):

For windows 10 PC's, the following macro may be used for scripting menus that provides colored output of a list of options with the capacity to highlight the selected option. For non windows 10 pc's, the macro may still be used, however  color output will be disabled.

For an alternative that supports colored menu output on other windows versions, see [my answer to a similar question on stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64399689/12343998)

```bat
==================================================================
@Echo off
:# [Menu] Macro Author: T3RRY = Version: 1.0.5
:# Supports Coloring of menu on Windows 10
:# IMPORTANT - RESERVED VARIABLES: \n [Menu]*
:#  - [Menu] macro variables prefixed with [Menu] to avoid potential conflict with other script variables.
:#  - \n is a standard definition of an escaped linefeed for creating multiline Macro variables.

:# Menu macro escaped for Definition with DelayedExpansion Enabled. Ensures correct Environment:
 If not "!" == "" (
  Setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
 )

:# Version control. Assigns flag true if system is windows 10. Flag used to apply color with Virtual terminal codes.
 Set "[menu]Win10="
 Ver | Findstr /LIC:" 10." > nul && Set "[menu]Win10=true"

:# Test if virtual terminal codes enabled ; enable if false
:# removes [menu]win10 flag definition if version does not support Virtual Terminal sequences
 If defined [menu]Win10 (
  Reg Query HKCU\Console | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /LIC:"VirtualTerminalLevel    REG_DWORD    0x1" > nul || (
    Reg Add HKCU\Console /f /v VirtualTerminalLevel /t REG_DWORD /d 1
  ) > Nul || Set "[menu]Win10="
 )

(Set \n=^^^

%= Newline var \n for multi-line macro definition - Do not modify. =%)

:# Key index list Allows maximum 36 menu options [ 0 indexed ]. Component of Menu Macro
 Set "[menu]Key_List=0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

:# Get console width for dividing line
 for /F "usebackq tokens=2* delims=: " %%W in (`mode con ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /LIC:"Columns"`) do Set /A "[menu]Console_Width=%%W"

:# Build Menu option color array [ RGB colormix ; red biased scaling darker. ]
 If defined [menu]Win10 For /F %%E in ('Echo prompt $E^|cmd')Do Set "\E=%%E"

 Set "[menu]i=0"
 If defined [menu]Win10 (
  Set "[Menu]Color_Off=%\E%[0m"
  For /L %%i in (232 -4 96)Do (
   Set /A "[menu]BB=(%%i/4)+50,[menu]GG=%%i-[menu]BB,[menu]RR=[menu]GG+[menu]BB+(%%i/2)"
   Set "[menu]Color[![menu]i!]=%\E%[38;2;![menu]RR!;![menu]GG!;![menu]BB!m"
   Set /A [menu]i+=1
 ))
 Set "[menu]i="

:# Define highlight color to use for a selected option
 If defined [menu]Win10 (
  Set "[menu]Highlight_Color=%\E%[0m%\E%[48;2;50;150;200m%\E%[31m%\E%[K"
 )

:# Assign Flag true to enable Highlighting of selected option.
:# - Clears screen before menu is output in order to count line position of options.
:# - Highlight will only be seen if the screen output is visible for a noticible length of time after
:# - expansion of the [Menu] macro. Use 'Pause', 'Timeout' or another method of effecting a delay if the screen buffer
:# - will be refreshed or scrolled by subsequent output immediately after menu selection to allow highlight to be seen.
:# - If not defined as true, screen will not be cleared prior to menu output and selection will not be highlighted.
 If defined [menu]Win10 (
  Set "[menu]Highlight=true"
 )

:# Force console line dimensions to a size that supports highlight mode by preventing buffer scroll
 If /I "%[menu]Highlight%" == "true" (
  for /F "usebackq tokens=2* delims=: " %%W in (`mode con ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /LIC:"Lines"`) do If %%W LSS 40 Mode ![menu]Console_Width!,40
 )

:# Build dividing line for menu output.
 Set "[menu]Divider=" & For /L %%i in (2 1 %[menu]Console_Width%)Do Set "[menu]Divider=![menu]Divider!-"

:# Define dividing line Color
 If defined [menu]Win10 (
  Set "[menu]Divider=%\E%[33m%\E%[4m![menu]Divider!%\E%[0m"
 )

:# Menu macro Usage: %Menu% "quoted" "list of" "options"
:# Supports 36 options [ options are zero indexed ]

     Set [Menu]=For %%n in (1 2)Do if %%n==2 (%\n%
%= Clear screen if highlight flag true  =%  If /I "^![menu]Highlight^!" == "true" CLS%\n%
%= Output Dividing Line                 =%  Echo(^^![menu]Divider^^!%\n%
%= Reset Index value for Opt[#]         =%  Set "[menu]Index=0"%\n%
%= Undefine choice option key list      =%  Set "[menu]Choice_Keys="%\n%
%= For Each in list;                    =%  For %%G in (^^![menu]Options^^!)Do If not ^^![menu]Index^^! GTR 35 (%\n%
%= For Option Index value               =%   For %%i in (^^![menu]Index^^!)Do (%\n%
%= Build the Choice key list and Opt[#] =%    Set "[menu]Choice_Keys=^![menu]Choice_Keys^!^![menu]Key_List:~%%i,1^!"%\n%
%= arrays using the character at the    =%    Set "[menu]Opt[^![menu]Key_List:~%%i,1^!]=%%~G"%\n%
%= current substring index.             =%    Set "[menu]Option_Output=%%~G"%\n%
%= Display ; removing # variable prefix =%    Echo(^^![menu]Color[%%i]^^![^^![menu]Key_List:~%%i,1^^!] ^^![menu]Option_Output:#=^^!![menu]Color_Off!%\n%
%= Store line number of options         =%    Set "[menu]Line#^![menu]Key_List:~%%i,1^!=%%i"%\n%
%= Increment Opt[#] Index var 'Index'   =%    Set /A "[menu]Index+=1"%\n%
%= Close Index loop                     =%   )%\n%
%= Close Options loop                   =%  )%\n%
%= Output Dividing Line                 =%  Echo(^^![menu]Divider^^!%\n%
%= Select option by character index     =%  For /F "Delims=" %%o in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\Choice.exe /N /C:^^![menu]Choice_Keys^^!')Do (%\n%
%= Assign return var 'OPTION' with the  =%   Set "[menu]Selection=^![menu]Opt[%%o]^!"%\n%
%= Highlight selected option with Line# =%   If /I "^![menu]Highlight^!" == "true" (For /F "Delims=" %%X in ("^![menu]Line#%%o^!")Do For /F "Delims=" %%Y in ('Set /A "%%X+2"')Do Echo(%\E%[%%Y;1H^^![menu]Highlight_Color^^!{^^![menu]Key_List:~%%X,1^^!} ^^![menu]Opt[%%o]^^!![menu]Color_Off!)%\n%
%= value selected from Opt[#] array.    =%   If /I "^![menu]Selection^!" == "Exit"   CLS ^& Exit /B 1%\n%
%= Exit type determines Errorlevel.     =%   If /I "^![menu]Selection^!" == "Previous" CLS ^& Exit /B 0%\n%
%= Return to previous script on Exit    =%  )%\n%
%= Move cursor to end of menu field     =%  If /I "^![menu]Highlight^!" == "true" For /F "Delims=" %%Y in ('Set /A [menu]Index + 2')Do Echo(%\E%[%%Y;1H%\n%
%= Capture Macro input - Options List   =% )Else Set [menu]Options=
========================================== :# End Definition of Menu Macro

:# Usage example
:Menu
 %[Menu]% Exit Demo list of options to select from. Each Displayed with different color tone and index key for selecting the desired choice. "Doublequote multiword options"
 Pause
Goto :Menu
:# Selected option returned in '[menu]Selection' variable.
```

Answer (score 0):

@T3RR0R

Thank you very much. Did you type that all up just for me? Thank You.
Some of you are on a different level when it comes to this stuff and I find it truly amazing and inspiring.  Thank You again.   The things I spend weeks on just trying to do or learn to do you guys seem to do in mere minutes.
I'm getting to be an old man now, things are harder to grasp but I do not want to give up as I like this hobby. Using a computer and fixing them is one thing but doing any type of coding is another world and it is difficult. I just realized I have been using Windows for over 30 years now. Jeez!  I should know how to make BAT files I do not. I understand just 1 line commands.
I started with BAT files as it seemed the easiest but I'm wondering if I should focus on Powershell instead.  One of the nephew's kids told me that Batch files are pretty much dead and that Powershell is superior.  They seem similar but I haven't jumped into the pool.  The question is should I switch to Powershell? are Bat files done?

Comment: Mister G, you have duplicate accounts apparently that need merged. Sounds like you want a simpler solution that is easier to comprehend which may use PowerShell? I'm confused because I added that solution first and thought you downvoted me for it. It sounds like that may have been exactly what you were looking for though and it may have been helpful to you, right? PowerShell is more Windows modern, way more robust than batch, and it usually takes a lot less & simpler logic to get what a dictionary in batch logic takes code wise. Definitely give PowerShell a shot at some point for something.